# Warum werden die niederwertigen Zahlen in Deutsch vertauscht?

Tags: numbers

Ich lerne gerade Spanisch und stelle fest, dass im Deutschen die beiden niederwertigsten Zahlen vertauscht werden. Also 37 ist *siebenunddreißig*. Im Spanischen wäre das *treinta y siete*.

Gibt es eine Quelle in der Entwicklung der Sprache dazu?

Comment: Same question in English: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5009/1224

Comment: @Em1, ich wusste nicht mehr genau, wie wir das mit "Duplikat bis auf die Sprache" halten.

Comment: @CarstenS Mein letzter Stand ist, dass wir ein "This question has also an answer in English" einbetten. Ich muss nur zugeben, dass ich zu faul bin, das gerade nachzuschauen.

Comment: @Em1, ich wollte damit vor allem sagen, dass meine Close-Vote wahrscheinlich falsch ist.

Comment: Ok. Danke.  Da gibt es in der Tat einige antworten.